# New membership price set not being used for manual (back-office) renewals

Tags: civicontribute, civimember

Our organization recently updated membership prices for the first time in a while and the first time since going to CiviCRM. We updated and renamed the price set and attached it to our online joining and renewals page. It works fine there. New joiners get the new prices and renewals are getting the new prices.

However, when we went to process some offline renewals, the pre-filled renewal price in the 'Renew Membership' pop-up window is showing the old prices. In fact, experimenting by selecting a different membership level confirms that it is drawing on the old price set.

We are completely unable to determine where this form is getting its prices from. The old price set still exists on the system, but it does not appear to be taking it from the old price set since we experimented by changing some values in that with no change in the pop-up renewal form.

We are flummoxed. Can anyone point us to where to look to get this sorted out? Thanks.

Also, should be be concerned that the auto-renew option will pick up the old prices as well?

We are on 5.35.2

Comment: is it possible that you have not changed the prices on the Membership Types themselves?

Comment: The auto-renew will be a problem. How you solve it may depend on the type of payment processor you are using. what is it?

Comment: petednx: Bullseye! That is exactly the problem. It has been so long we had forgotten there were even 'minimum price' levels set there. Thanks loads.

We use PayPal as our payment processor. Auto-renew is a relatively new option for us, and I dare say a bit of a mystery.  Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: i have put that above as an Answer - pls accept it. re autorenew perhaps comment at https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/41159/what-are-the-steps-for-changing-the-amount-for-a-recurring-payment-when-using-pa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check that you have changed the prices on the Membership Types themselves as they have a 'minimum amount' field which is what will apply as default, ie in situations where a Price Set is not overriding them

Comment: That's it.  Updated the prices there and all works just perfect.  Thanks very much.

Comment: i may have had you confused with de Oldefarte for a moment there